# PrismaClient Error: "PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser" in Next.js with next-auth/react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, prisma

I'm building a Next.js application and using the next-auth/react package for authentication. I have a server-side function that uses PrismaClient to fetch the current user's information based on their email. However, when I try to run this function, I encounter the following error:

[image]

I've checked my code and setup, and I'm confident that I'm using Prisma on the server-side. Here's the relevant code:

> ```
> import { getSession, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
> import prisma from '@/app/libs/prismadb';
>
> const getCurrentUser = async () => {
> try {
> const session = await getSession();
>
> if (!session?.user?.email) {
> return null;
>         }
>
> const currentUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
> where: {
> email: session.user.email as string
>             }
>         });
>
> console.log("Current User is found:", currentUser);
>
> if (!currentUser) {
> return null;
>         }
>
> return currentUser;
> catch (error) {
> console.log(error);
> return null;
>     }
> }
>
> export default getCurrentUser;
> ```

I've verified that my prismadb configuration is set up correctly, and I'm using the correct versions of the relevant packages. I've also ensured that this code is running on the server side.

I'm not sure why I'm still getting this error even though I'm using Prisma in a server-side context. Is there something specific I might be missing in my setup? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

I've already taken the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

- Verified that my prismadb configuration is correctly set up and the connection to the database is established.
- 
- Confirmed that the provided code is being executed on the server side by using server-side functions.
- 
- Checked the versions of the Prisma, Next.js, and other relevant packages to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Cn you show the component where you are calling `getCurrentUser` ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are invoking PrismaClient in client side even if the code is run async model. Pls try to move Prisma code into server api, then, call the api in the client.